# Can you set an NSInteger as NULL in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsinteger

I am trying to set an NSInteger to NULL.
Though the compiler does not give any error, but I am not sure if this is the right way to do it.
Can you set an NSInteger as NULL in ios..? Or is it forbidden for some reason..?
Or Should I set it to Nil..?
Which is better practice..?

Thanks

Comment: `NULL` is just `0` which is why there is no issue.

Comment: http://nshipster.com/nil/

Comment: Setting it to NULL suggests it's a pointer. If it isn't a pointer I would just set it to 0.

Comment: Agree with the above comments, besides what would `NSInteger = NULL` mean? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @rmaddy It will still generate a warning.

Comment: @Sulthan `NSInteger x = NULL;` does not produce any warning. I'm not saying it is the right thing to do. But it shows no warning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are confusing `NSInteger` with an Objective-C class.

`NSInteger` is simply a `typedef`d integer:

```
#if __LP64__ || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
  typedef long NSInteger;
  typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
  typedef int NSInteger;
  typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

If you want something that holds a number which can be `nil` then you probably want [`NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsnumber_class/Reference/Reference.html).